# Anybody use FalkonSystem arDrone?

Tags: ros, ardrone, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

i found a roslaunch called "FalkorSystems"  https://github.com/FalkorSystems/falkor_ardrone for navigation on vision.

i dont know how install, 'cause don't find any tutorial about.

Anybody has used this "launch"? How did you installed?

greetings

P.s. i have installed Ardrone_autonomy, i use Ubuntu 12.04 and have ArDrone 2.0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46834/anybody-use-falkonsystem-ardrone?/) by [juanproject](https://answers.ros.org/users/3459/juanproject/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a rosbuild package; have you tried downloading it into your rosbuild workspace, running rosmake on it, and then running the launch file as indicated?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsoltani](https://answers.ros.org/users/15361/hsoltani/) on 2014-05-21**:
Can I use catkin? I have tried downloading it into catkin workspace and running catkin_make:

cd catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/FalkorSystems/falkor_ardrone.git -b hydro-devel
catkin_make

But the package don't install. I'm using hydro version. How can I work with rosbuild?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-21**:
No, it's a rosbuild package. You can't use catkin with it; you'll have to create a separate rosbuild workspace that is overlaid on top of your catkin workspace. Take a look at http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin .

**Comment by [hsoltani](https://answers.ros.org/users/15361/hsoltani/) on 2014-05-21**:
Thanks for your help. I try to do it.